# Primeng with jhipster

Tags: jhipster, primeng

I have jhipster 6.6.0 version and I want to use primeng in my application generated with jhipster. After executing the command:

```
 yo jhipster-primeng
```

eveything is ok but then I run:

```
npm install
```

and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cdk@^8.2.14.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'jhipster-ui-libs'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\48696\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-04T16_19_42_448Z-debug.log
```

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the package `@angular/animations` installed? It seems you are missing some dependencies. If you are missing this package simply do `npm install --save @angular/animations`.

Comment: Yes I installed it, but it didn't help. In addition, when generating applications with the older version of jhipster everything is ok. have you tried to integrate primeng with the latest version of jhipster?

Comment: What is jhipster-ui-libs in the error? Did you clone my project? https://github.com/gmarziou/jhipster-ui-libs/commits/primeng-jhipster-6

Comment: Yes, i cloned your project but after this I also created my own from scratch with jhipster generator and also got the same error. After that I switched to the older version of jhipster, I created another app and I was able to integrate this app with primeng without such errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The installation of primeng seems to always be a bit tricky, no matter the version. The instructions in this answer have been tested with JHipster 6.6.0.

**1. Install PrimeNG**

You must install a version of PrimeNG that is compatible with whatever version of angular JHipster is using. In this case JHipster 6.6.0 uses angular 8 so I installed version [8.1.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng/v/8.1.1) of PrimeNG (the latest version 8 available).

You can use the following command if you use npm:

```
npm i primeng@8.1.1 primeicons @angular/animations
```

Or the following command if you use yarn:

```
yarn add primeng@8.1.1 primeicons @angular/animations
```

Remember that, in the future, you might be required to specify a compatible version of `@angular/animations` too.

**2. Import the required PrimeNG modules**

Now you must import the required modules, in my case just to test things I wanted to add a PrimeNG button so I imported the `ButtonModule`.

Open the `[your-entity].module.ts` file (or `home.module.ts`) and add the following lines:

```js
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button'; 
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., BrowserAnimationsModule, ButtonModule],
  ...
})
```

In this second step it is **very important** to never import modules from `primeng/primeng`. You must use the specific module sub-folder like I did `from 'primeng/button'`.

**3. Import the required css files**

Open your `vendor.scss` file (or vendor.css if you do not use SCSS) and add the following:

```css
...
// Import PrimeNG source files
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
...
```

At this point you should be able to add a `p-button` to your `*.component.html` file and it should be rendered without errors. Open two consoles and run `.\mvnw` and `npm start` respectively, as usual.

**4. Add any extra dependency you need (Optional)**

Very common example: you need to use `ChartJS`, you will have to add the dependency accordingly e.g.: `npm i chart.js`. Then add the import to your `*.module.ts` file:

```js
import { ChartModule } from 'primeng/chart';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., ChartModule],
  ...
})
```

And finally add the bundle to your `vendor.ts` like this:

```js
import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle';
```

And now you should be able to add a chart like explained in the official [primeng documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart).

---

I've published a repo in my github with the very minimum configuration required to start using PrimeNG in your JHipster 6.6.0 installation. You can find it [here](https://github.com/vicpermir/jhipster-primeng).

Changes, fixes and suggestions are welcome. I did this in a bit of a rush, my apologies.

Comment: Many thanks! So now if I want to use other functions from prmieng available here: [link](https://primefaces.org/primeng),  just import it in the appropriate module `*.module.ts`? For example, if i want to use Listbox: [link](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox), do I have to add some dependency?

Comment: In the case of `Listbox` you don't need any extra dependency, so it should be as easy as adding the import and module in your `*.module.ts` like I did with the Button. Then you can use it just like the examples in the official documentation.

Comment: In fact I just tried it and everything works, you can check the latest commits to my repo. Also fixed the missing `primeicons` dependency and updated the answer accordingly (all I did was `npm i primeicons` and added the css to the `vendor.scss` file).