# Drag/drop reordered lists in JHipster: What's recommended?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, jhipster

Looking for some advice/guidance.  I want to implement (what I think is a pretty standard feature) a drag/drop reorderable list in JHipster 6.7.1.

To be really specific, imagine you have created a custom ordered list of objects.  Apart from adding/removing items from the list, a user will also want to reorder the list.  For example, imagine wishing to make `[Epsilon]` second in order (after `[Alpha]`):

```
(before)         (after)
[Alpha]          [Alpha]
[Beta] \---+     [Epsilon]
[Gamma]    |     [Beta]
[Delta]    |     [Gamma]
[Epsilon]--+     [Delta]
```

Simply drag/drop `[Epsilon]` to somewhere between `[Alpha]` and `[Beta]`, and drop it.  The list is rerendered with the new ordering.  Done.  Obviously, on the back end, the code must persist/manage the new indices/ordering, but the user experience is intuitive and fast.

A drag/drop reorderable would allow users to quickly drag and drop the items into any desired ordering.  I've implemented this sort of thing many times over the years using simple JavaScript libraries.  I was hoping JHipster 6.7.1 would help quickly arrive at a good modern solution.

[Ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) doesn't seem to provide anything more than static tools.  (No drag/drop.)

[Angular Materials](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#reordering-lists) **looks perfect!!**  After struggling to get things moving in JHipster, even trying the [JHipster Angular Material generator](https://github.com/contribution-jhipster-uga/generator-jhipster-angular-material-integration), I learnt to my amazement that [JHipster does not (and may never) support Angular Materials](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10958#issuecomment-566102235)!  Something to do with Bootstrap stepping on Angular Material's toes...  *Ok*.

I then tried [SortableJS](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) using [ngx-sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/ngx-sortablejs).  No luck.

I found a few references to [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) as a popular toolset for JHipster developers.  [These Drag/Drop set of directives](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dragdrop) look useful, but no examples show a simple reorderable list (dragging from one list to another is not what I am talking about).  The [picklist directives](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist) are also not what I'm looking for.  I'll continue playing with PrimeNG...

In the meantime, instead of thrashing on my own, I'm turning to the good folk on StackOverflow for some wisdom.

- Has anyone implemented a simple drag/drop list order mechanism in a JHipster application?
- What library/method works within JHipster?  Did SortableJS/NGX-SortableJS work for you?  PrimeNG?  Something else?
- I noticed a thing called [NG-Dragula](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html)... Has anyone tried this inside a JHipster application?
- Should I use Vue, or React or some other front end (rather than Angular)?  Would that provide me with more flexibility?
- Am I overthinking this. and missing something obvious?

I'd really like to try using JHipster/Angular, but I am early enough in development to be open to other options...

Thanks in advance!

[Development environment is: Windows 10 Pro; IntelliJ 2019.3.3; OpenJDK 13; Node 12.15.0; npm 6.13.7; Gradle 6.1.1; Chrome v80.0.3987.116]

[PS: I'm happy to provide any more details.  Just ask!]

Comment: For PrimeNG integration to JHipster there is a detailed answer from vicpermir here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085001/7773582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/), I found [OrderList](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/orderlist), which provides a drag/drop reordering.  It is not as simple and elegant as the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#reordering-lists) version.  In some ways it is more ambitious, perhaps a little overengineered.  Sometimes less is more, and work needs to be done to "dumb down" the widget, but so far it works.

Big thanks to [Jochen Gebsattel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7773582/jochen-gebsattel) for the link to the [Jhipster/PrimeNG integration guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085001/7773582).  Works like a charm.

After that, I added the following to my module:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { OrderListModule } from 'primeng/orderlist';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., BrowserAnimationsModule, OrderListModule],
  ...
})
export class ...Module {}
```

I added the following to my component:

```
export class ...Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
books: string[] = [
                    'Moby Dick',
                    'Brave New World',
                    'Great Expectations',
                    'Wuthering Heights',
                    'King James Bible'
                  ];
lheight: string;

...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lheight = String( 41 * this.books.length ) + 'px';
  }

...

  onReorder(): void {
    console.log(this.books); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }

}
```

Then I added the following to my component's template:

```
...

<p-orderList [value]="books" dragdrop="true" (onReorder)="onReorder()" [listStyle]="{'height': lheight}">
  <ng-template let-book pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
      <p>{{book}}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-orderList>

...
```

Notice, the `lheight` property allows me to dynamically resize the list window so all items are always in view.

PrimegNG looks like it has some nice features.  It's not Angular Material, but as my old grandfather used to say: "If you can't get the one you love, you best love the one you can get!".

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the Sudharaka's demo project https://github.com/SudharakaP/JHipsterProtractorDragAndDrop,
I implemented @angular/cdk/drag-drop in a Jhipster 6.7.0 project.

I used jHipster standard generator and then added the cdk library with `npm install @angular/cdk@8.2.3` (the last module 9.0.1 doesn't work with @angular/core 8.2.14)

Import the DragDropModule in your module:

`import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
imports: [
  DragDropModule
]`

Then you can use the DragDrop directives as explained in official documentation:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, Mauro!  If I get a chance, I'll try it out, and provide feedback of my experience.