# Can not add PRIMENG using yo jhipster-primeng v3.0.0 on newly generated jhipster apps

Tags: angular, jhipster, primeng

I am confused which part I missed out.
A newly generated jhipster monolithic app, which run normally, after I add primeng using yo jhipster-primeng, the app can not compile properly when I try ./mvnw.

When starting yo jhipster-primeng, 
I was greeted with Welcome to the JHipster primeng generator! v3.0.0.And then a series of questions and answers.
After that, I slowly see information as follows:
1. Unable to find src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts or missing required jhipster-needle. file rewrite failed.
If I checked the location, vendor.ts is available.

2. At the end of the generation there is a message: found 4 vulnerabilities(3 low, 1 moderate) run 'npm audit fix' to fix them, or 'npm audit' for details
3. I perform npm audit and there is a suggestion to instal quill. So I run npm install quill@1.3.7. After that, I got 3 low vulnerabilities only. The moderate is gone.
4. But when I run ./mvnw. I still end up with error. I screenshoot the lastest part of the error:

```
    [INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/misc/validation/validationdemo.module.ts:4:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../shared'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 4 import { SimpleAppSharedModule } from '../../../shared';
[INFO]                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO] src/main/webapp/app/primeng/misc/progressspinner/progressspinnerdemo.module.ts:4:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../shared'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 4 import { SimpleAppSharedModule } from '../../../shared';
[INFO]                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 1
[INFO] npm ERR! simple-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal`
[INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[INFO] npm ERR!
[INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the simple-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build:main script.
[INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[INFO]
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\alvin.TMI-JKT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-10T01_12_54_616Z-debug.log
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 1
[INFO] npm ERR! simple-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main`
[INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[INFO] npm ERR!
[INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the simple-app@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:build script.
[INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[INFO]
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\alvin.TMI-JKT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-10T01_12_55_228Z-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-10T08:12:55+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:npm (webpack build dev) on project simple-app: Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

The yo-rc.json is as follows:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.app.simple",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.8.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "simpleApp",
    "packageName": "com.app.simple",
    "packageFolder": "com/app/simple",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "hazelcast",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "NTU5MTlmNWU0NDM5M2U0MjQyYTg5ZGUwY2Y2YmVlZDIwNDFmNWE3NTc2ZDlkY2ZiOTU3YTgyNmY1NDYzZjA5NzFjNzk2YmI2ZTQ2MjNiYWMwM2RkNWM0MmVmMTY5OTIzYWUxZDhjNTI1YzUxYWQwY2QwNzE4OTMzZGI0MzhmMjM=",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1586447033650,
    "testFrameworks": ["protractor"],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": ["en"],
    "blueprints": []
  }
}
```

JHipster version is 6.8.0
java version is 11.0.6
node version is 13.8.0

Any suggestions where I should explore? Thank you.

Comment: You'd better open an issue at https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng Alternatively, adding primeng manually to an existing project is not very difficult, see primeng official doc and an example at https://github.com/gmarziou/jhipster-ui-libs/commit/cbfbd1854f77b3389582e610c260e73c474b13bd

Comment: Thanks Gael Marziou, I have opened an issue in github.com. In the meantime, I will try to manually adding primeng into my existing project following your example.

Comment: If you need a guide you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60085001/1031296), it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Vicpermir. I have read your answer. Thank you.

Comment: vicpermir, I still got error 'p-table' is not a known element even though I have primeicons.css, theme.css, and prime.min.css added in vendor.scss. On pure Angular application, I have no problem with it and they are kept in angular.json. Do you have any idea, why I still got "not a known element" ?

Comment: Never mind vicpermir. At last, I have found out why it doesn't work and how t o make it work. It is very much related to version compatibility between jhipster generated angular apps and the primeng version.